# How to find values that are not shown in all years?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres that is almost 14,000 rows. I'm noticing values that are present in some years, but not present in others. Right now I have a count of the values in these specific columns for 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, and so on. I just want to make it easier for myself to select the values that are only in 2016 and 2017, but not in the other years.

Ex: I found "13HAZ02";"Housekeeping" in 2016 and 2017 as a type and description.

This is how I'm counting:

```
select type, descr, count(*) as count
from (
select *
from table    
where date >= '2016-01-01' and date <= '2016-12-31'
) as a
group by type, descr
order by count desc
```

I'm adding a where not but I'm not using it correctly. I receive this error: date/time field value out of range.

```
select type, descr, count(*) as count
from (
select *
from table    
where date >= '2016-01-01' and date <= '2016-12-31'
) as a
where not date > '2015-12-31'
group by type, descr
order by count desc
```

Maybe I'm over complicating it, so I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Your question requirement is different from what you have in your query. You say that you want to see values that are only in 2016 and 2017 but your filter is to 2007 ? Really confusing. Consider adding sample data and from the sample what would be your desired result.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks Jorge, I didn't realize that I was still searching for 2007 and I'll add a sample of the data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
a.type, a.descr, count(year) as count
FROM (
       SELECT 
         type,
         descr,
         date_part(`year`, date) as year
       FROM table    
       WHERE year > 2015 and year < 2018
) AS a
GROUP BY a.year
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  type, descr,
  count(*) as count_total,
  count(*) filter (where date >= '2016-01-01' and date <= '2016-12-31') as count_in_years
from table
group by type, descr
having count(*) = count(*) filter (where date >= '2016-01-01' and date <= '2016-12-31')
order by count desc
```